# ConTeXt - Unwanted empty page with doublesided document

Tags: page-breaking, context, double-sided

When I use `alternative=doublesided` in `\setuppagenumbering` I get an extra white page if my document has an odd number of pages. How can I get rid of it?

Following I post a minimal example to get the extra page:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\starttext

test

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `page=no`.

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,page=no]
\starttext
test
\stoptext
```

---

#### How did you find that out?

It's not documented (at least not in any obvious place) so what I did was search the code

```sh
grep -r --include=*.mkiv setuppagenumbering "$(kpsexpand '$TEXMFCONTEXT')/tex/context"
```

The result [`strc-pag.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-pag.mkiv) looked most promising, so I opened the file.  There the macro [`\strc_pagenumbers_flush_final_page`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/a8f63ee70a866cce43ee4b1bb5ba95ef8044243f/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-pag.mkiv#L345-L351) looks very much like flushing an empty page if the parameter `page` is set to `no`.  So I tried adding the parameter `page=no` and it worked.

Comment: There's also `\installpagebreakhandler{last}{}`